# Dragdealer initialisation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

EDIT - I managed to work it out thanks to a friendly commenter below. It turned out to be pretty basic as I wasn't calling my function in the right place. I moved the function call to the click event that opened the group of divs where I'm using DragDealer and it now works.

I am trying to set up the [Dragdealer](http://code.ovidiu.ch/dragdealer/) plugin for a slider on a site i'm building

My slider button isn't moveable until I resize my browser window slightly. The slider itself is in a hidden div on page load, so i've connected the call to DragDealer to when it's parent div opens, but it's still not initialising.

```
<div id="assetTable">
    <div id="assetTableHeaders">
        <div class="investmentHeading odd">Investment option</div>
            <div class="investmentHeading even">Allocation</div>
        </div>
        <div class="investmentOption" id="global_property">
            <div class="investmentTitle"><a href="#">Global Property</a></div>
            <div class="investmentSlider">
                <div class="slider short">
                    <div class="slider-bg">
                        <div class="slider-indicator"><div class="active">&nbsp;</div></div>
                <div id="slider_global_property" class="dragdealer">
                                                <div class="handle ir" style="left: 208px;">Drag</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="investmentInput">
    <input type="text" id="input_global_property" class="investmentPercent" name="input_global_property" value="0%">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

"asseTtable" is hidden until expanded by an onclick handler via jquery

```
function setUpSliders() {
var val_global_property = document.getElementById('input_global_property');

var sliderGlobalProperty = new Dragdealer('slider_global_property',
    {
        steps: 100,
        animationCallback: function(x, y)
    {
        val_global_property.value = (Math.round(x * 100) + '%');
    }
});

$('#input_global_property').change(function(){
    sliderGlobalProperty.setStep(stripPercentages());
        return false;
    });
```

}

```
$('#investmentOption_selfSelect').click(function(){
    setUpSliders();
});
```

Comment: Had to read that twice, was sure it said you were trying to set up a **drugdealer** plugin at first? Would be much cooler really!

Comment: You should show the code you have. PS. this is not a list.

Comment: @Juhana - thanks, list comment removed. I'll paste in some code now, do you have experience with this plugin in order to help debug or is that just a general SO housekeeping comment?

Comment: HTML is good, but I meant the JavaScript.

Comment: Where are you calling `setUpSliders()`?

Comment: Hi, I think I figured it out. I was opening it's parent div already somewhere else, so I added the call to setUpSliders() there and it appears to be working now. Thanks for talking me through it! I may edit the answer above and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem with DragDealer and found this answer here via Google.
I was transitioning from one HTML page view to another using JQuery as shown, and I was calling my setUpSliders() before the fadeOut/fadeIn finished. After reading this answer, I changed my code to call setUpSliders() after the fadeIn completed. This fixed the problem. This example may help someone else.

```
//switch from Home page to Charts page DOM
var switchToChartsPage = function () {
    $("#HomePage").fadeOut(fadeOutTime, function () {
        $("#chartsPage").fadeIn(fadeInTime, function () { setUpSliders(); }); 
        //Note: delay setting up DragDealer sliders until after DOM settles
    });
    startChartPage();
}

var startChartPage = function () {
    showPanels = true; //initialization switch
      <some code removed>
    carouselPaneCount = buildCharts(); //build the charts and tables html
    //setUpSliders(); // do NOT set up the sliders here - see comment above
    $(".chartspagetitle").text(pageTitleTextLine[currentLocalStorageKey]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to work it out thanks to a friendly commenter @Juhana. It turned out to be pretty basic as I wasn't calling my function in the right place. I moved the function call to the click event that opened the group of divs where I'm using DragDealer and it now works.

Comment: I had a similar problem where new DragDealer(...) was not being effective, because I had the slider hidden on the page at the time. I changed my code to call the constructor at the point I first make the slider visible. Now it works fine.